# MS access database in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I followed a tutorial on the internet to create my own database. I succesfully built a program upon it. Then I created an access .mdb file(another database) and then I just changed the database which the program connected to, to the one which I created.

I just made that one change. But then it started showing me error whenever I tried to update using

```
da.update(ds,"Phone Book")
```

where da is data adapter and ds is data set.

> The error was: " syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

I have just changed the DB that the program is connecting to. I did not change the code one bit.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I searched for this on google, and one thing which I read was, that access database might be only read only or something. But I unchecked the read only box, so I don't know whether it still might be the problem. Although, I don't think there is a problem with the code

EDIT: I just discovered now, that even if I change the table which is being referred to, it throws up the same error.

Comment: And why does it work with one table then? Shouldn't it throw an error with every table?

Comment: It just this: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" and btw, VB.NET shows this exception while I am trying to create a new row in the database

Comment: I asked you to show us the SQL which triggers the Access syntax error.    Without seeing that, I definitely can not help.  Good luck.

Comment: I got it. Really dumb. My field names had a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the first database probably used something like Sql Server Express. That's a completely different kind of database then Access, with a different providers, different dialect of SQL, connection string, etc. Why would you think you can change all that without breaking some of your code?

Comment: First, in both cases I used only a .mdb database.
Second, I have just changed the name of the database. Even the rows and columns have the same name as the previous one

Comment: shouldn't someone be answering this question?